# Robot State Publisher outputs negative delays

Tags: urdf, robot-state-publisher, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a doubt regarding the robot state publisher node. I am loading an urdf file validated with the check_urdf. When launching the robot state publisher, I obtain some suspicious values on the Average Delay field.

I am running under Electric version and the launch file I am using looks like the following:

```
<!-- robot urdf model -->
<param name="robot_description" command="cat $(find robot_base)/model/robot_base.urdf" />

<!-- robot state publisher node -->
<node pkg ="robot_state_publisher"
      type="state_publisher"
      name="robot_state_publisher">
</node>
```

The tf_monitor outputs this result:

```
RESULTS: for all Frames

Frames:
Frame: /front_laser published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.499885 Max Delay: 0
Frame: /rear_laser published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.499884 Max Delay: 0
Frame: /vertical_laser published by /robot_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.499883 Max Delay: 0

All Broadcasters:
Node: /robot_state_publisher 51.2438 Hz, Average Delay: -0.499884 Max Delay: 0
```

I am not sure if this negative Average Delay values are due to some error or not. When adding a new frame from the odometry node which links to the robot_state_publisher base_link, the Average Delay outputs a more coherent value like 9.61504e-05.

Is everything running as expected or I have some bug on my setup?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11380/robot-state-publisher-outputs-negative-delays/) by [joan](https://answers.ros.org/users/881/joan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 245 on 2011-09-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the [tf FAQ](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/FAQ#Why_do_I_see_negative_average_delay_in_tf_monitor.3F) for the answer to this. This is normal behavior for certain nodes that timestamp data in the future.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3